# truncated Functional data analysis + identify subgroups?

Tags: time-series, clustering, panel-data, functional-data-analysis

I have intensive longitudinal data about heartbeat rates, movement activity measured by actiwatch, respiration rates etc... collected from about 100 patients at a terminal care.

For each patient, data collection starts when one enters to the terminal care and data collection is terminated when a patient pass away, i.e., data collection period differ per patient.

What I would like to understand from this data:

- Can we identify subgroups based on intensive longitudinal data? (e.g., is there any patterns to be identify for patients who live longer at the terminal care or not? This could help us to allocate medical access for each patient in a more efficiently way.)
- Is there any common sequence in variable change prior to patients' death? (e.g., activity  change -> heart beat change -> respiration rate change etc...). Understanding this could indicate which variable should be focused on when a patient is in an extreme critical condition.

I thought that this type of questions could be analyzed with functional data analysis with clustering or time-series analysis. However, I could not find a statistical method handling this type of data.

Is there any suggestion or paper which could be used in this case?